# CSS style and app.js not loading

Tags: functions, customization, themes, css, wp-enqueue-style

I'm brand new at theme development.
My directory is the following:

[image]

I should see, in the page source (even if I have a blank page) the app.js loaded, but I don't.
This is what I see:

[image]

what is wrong in the function.php:

```
<?php
function load_stylesheets()
{

        wp_register_style('stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css','',1,'all');
        wp_enqueue_style('stylesheet');

        wp_register_style('custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/app.css',''1,'all');
        wp_enqueue_style('custom');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_stylesheets');

function load_javascript()
{

        wp_register_script('custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/app.js', 'jquery',1,true);
        wp_enqueue_script('custom');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_javascript');
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: The file needs to be functions.php, plural.

Comment: Holy crap!!! I was stuck here for hours. you're my hero.